# sending filename from client to server using socket of python

Tags: python, web-services, sockets, websocket

In my code I send an image from client to server.everything works perfectly well,but when i try to send the filename of the image from server to client i keep waiting and i don't get any errors .
here's my code:

client:

```
import socket
import pickle


host = socket.gethostname()

port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host , port))



f = open("test.png", "rb")

while True:

    veri = f.read()

    if not veri:

        break

    s.send(veri)

f.close()

print "image successfully sent"




data = s.recv(1024)
#data_arr=pickle.loads(data)

print "data recieved is :",data


s.close()
```

Server:

```
import socket
import pickle
from PIL import Image
import os


host = socket.gethostname()

port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)

client , adress = s.accept()

print "successfully connected to",adress

f = open("server.png", "wb")

while True:

    veri = client.recv(1024)

    if not veri:

        break

    f.write(veri)

f.close()

print "image recieved successfully"


T= os.path.abspath(f.name)

print "the path of the image is ",T

#data=pickle.dumps(T)
client.send(T)
print "binary data sent"

client.close()
```

Comment: Since the same channel is used, I think that the filename is read when reading the image data. Check your png file (the end) with an hex editor to confirm this.

Comment: You would have to send the size of the image first, to read just the required bytes, so it doesn't read the filename with the rest of the data.

Comment: i don't think this problem is related to filename particulary,i tried client.send(str(9))

Comment: and i get the same result

Comment: you have to send the size as binary (so the size if fixed), then read the same amount of bytes to get the size on the other end. Then you know how many bytes to read for the image and for the filename. First send your "header" containing the size(s) then send the data so the reciever knows how much data to read for each object.

Comment: i'm going to try that

Comment: another question:apart from filenames, why can't I send anything from server to client and I tried everything and  it doesn't seem to work